# Possible to disable Google ads images in WebView? I disabled links

Tags: android, webview, adsense

The mobile webpage loaded into the `WebView` displays Google ads. However the same ads are displayed inside the app as well. So it's too many ads.

I have tried to catch all links containing `googleads` and `googlesyndication` in the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and converting them to `""`. This was successful in a way that when you click on Google Ad, nothing happens.

However, I am unable to block any image. I have tried to catch the image and replace it with my image from `assets`, without any success. But the worse is that I actually do not see any image from Google Ads. They must have been hidden inside its `.js` files or something.

So now I have images with dead links.

Anyone managed to disable images of google ads the same way?

The code looks like this

```
  WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url.contains("googleads") || url.contains("googlesyndication")) {
           url = "";
           super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    return true;
       }
```

NOTE: We need client-side for the next few months, since server-side is inaccessible.